# get the last position of an item in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Basically I have a data frame and I wanted to filter the data based on a list of data. I'm using isin method to return boolean data.

```
  col1 col2
0  aaa    a
1  aaa    b
2  bbb    c
3  ccc    d
4  ccc    e
5  ddd    f
```

```
df.loc[df['col1'].isin(['aaa', 'ccc'])]

  col1 col2
0  aaa    a
1  aaa    b
3  ccc    d
4  ccc    e
```

It would return me all true entries.
What I wanted was to try to get the last true position of each combination:

```
  col1 col2
1  aaa    b
4  ccc    e
```

I can do this using loops extracting the last index on each iteration, but I was wondering if there is a way to do this with pandas methods, I've looked a lot in the documentation and haven't found it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `drop_duplicates()`

```
df.loc[df['col1'].isin(['aaa', 'ccc'])].drop_duplicates(subset = 'col1',keep='last')
```